# Code with event handler using "functional state update" working perfectly in React 17 does not work properly in React 18

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have observed a very strange behavior of React 18 compared to React 17 and I am wondering what I am doing wrong (since React 18 was not supposed to "break" existing code except for the small required adjustments in `index.tsx` (or `index.js`, respectively) regarding the import statement of ReactDOM and the main render function).

I would like to zoom a div with Ctrl + scroll wheel where the same "point" stays underneath my mouse arrow. Therefore, I need to translate my div while zooming.

**The following code works perfectly in React 17. In React 18 the "functional state update" (`setParams((params) => {...}`) does not work properly. `params.zoom` gets updated, however, `params.translateX` and `params.translateY` do not get updated. Is this maybe related to "state batching"? What can I do to solve this issue?**

Of course, I could move the event handler inside of my useEffect hook, but then I would have to create dependencies of `params` (like `[divElement, params]`) which I would like to avoid for performance reasons since my event handler would get removed/re-added everytime the state of `params` changes.

Here is the relevant code:

Interface for scale for zooming ("zoom") and 2D translation of zoomed div element:

```tsx
interface Parameters {
  zoom: number;
  translateX: number;
  translateY: number;
}
```

useState hook for `params`:

```tsx
const [params, setParams] = useState<Parameters>({
    zoom: 1,
    translateX: 0,
    translateY: 0,
  });
```

useRef hook for my div:

```tsx
const divElement: React.LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement> = useRef(null);
```

Event handler for my "wheel event" with functional (!) update of the state of `params`:

```tsx
const onWheel = useCallback((event: WheelEvent) => {
    if (event.ctrlKey) {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log('offsetX: ' + event.offsetX + ', offsetY: ' + event.offsetY);
      setParams((params) => {
        const newZoom: number = Math.min(
          Math.max(params.zoom + event.deltaY * 0.001, 0.2),
          1
        );
        const newTranslateX: number =
          params.translateX - event.offsetX * (newZoom - params.zoom);
        const newTranslateY: number =
          params.translateY - event.offsetY * (newZoom - params.zoom);
        return {
          zoom: newZoom,
          translateX: newTranslateX,
          translateY: newTranslateY,
        };
      });
    }
  }, []);
```

useEffect hook that registers my div as active event listener for "wheel event":

```tsx
useEffect(() => {
    const currentElement: HTMLDivElement | null = divElement.current;
    if (currentElement) {
      currentElement.addEventListener('wheel', onWheel, { passive: false });
      return () => {
        currentElement.removeEventListener('wheel', onWheel);
      };
    }
  }, [divElement, onWheel]);
```